# 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'translate' Inserting value to Mysql in Python

Tags: python, mysql

```
import dataset
db = dataset.connect(....)
table = db[...]
```

When I try to insert some value into Mysql table, this error occurred.

Sample Value I am inserting to the table:

```
print("Buy", ticker, price, date, OType, OSize)
Buy AAPL 93.4357142857 2016-05-12 Market 200
data = dict(Order_Side='Buy',Ticker=ticker, Price=price, 
                            Order_Date= date, Order_Type = OType, Volume = OSize )
table.insert(data)
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-3-b7ab0c98f72f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/SwigelUser/Documents/GitHub/Trading/Strategies/strat_MA_ExecTest.py', wdir='C:/Users/SwigelUser/Documents/GitHub/Trading/Strategies')

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 880, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\utils\site\sitecustomize.py", line 102, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/SwigelUser/Documents/GitHub/Trading/Strategies/strat_MA_ExecTest.py", line 69, in <module>
    MA_Stra(start_length=7,end_length=10,start_date=date(2016,5,12),end_date=date(2016,6,18))

  File "C:/Users/SwigelUser/Documents/GitHub/Trading/Strategies/strat_MA_ExecTest.py", line 66, in MA_Stra
    table.insert(data1)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dataset\persistence\table.py", line 87, in insert
    res = self.database.executable.execute(self.table.insert(row))

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 263, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1053, in _execute_clauseelement
    compiled_sql, distilled_params

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1405, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.reraise(*exc_info)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 187, in reraise
    raise value

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 164, in execute
    query = self.mogrify(query, args)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 143, in mogrify
    query = query % self._escape_args(args, conn)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 123, in _escape_args
    return dict((key, conn.literal(val)) for (key, val) in args.items())

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py", line 123, in <genexpr>
    return dict((key, conn.literal(val)) for (key, val) in args.items())

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 821, in literal
    return self.escape(obj, self.encoders)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\connections.py", line 814, in escape
    return escape_item(obj, self.charset, mapping=mapping)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 27, in escape_item
    val = encoder(val, mapping)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 110, in escape_unicode
    return u"'%s'" % _escape_unicode(value)

  File "C:\Users\SwigelUser\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pymysql\converters.py", line 73, in _escape_unicode
    return value.translate(_escape_table)

AttributeError: 'numpy.float64' object has no attribute 'translate'
```

What have caused this error? How could I solve this.
It seems like I entered too much code here,thus I will have to type lots of none sense in order to submit.

my price and date variable comes from a dataframe:

```
for i in range(len(All_Tickers)-1-len(Current_Date),len(All_Tickers)-1):
    price = All_Tickers[str(length) + 'day_MA'][i]
    date = All_Tickers['Date'][i+1]
```

According to the answer below, the problem should be the type of price is np.float64, how can I convert this variable to type float?

Comment: Since it turns out what you're doing involves pandas, the [`to_sql()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html) method may interest you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your library tries to format the provided arguments to a format MySQL will understand. To do so, it checks the type of each argument, to determine how the input should be formatted.

However, since your lib doesn't knows `numpy.float64`, it fallbacks to a default encoder, which happens to be one for **strings** (unicode). [Here is the relevent piece of code](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/converters.py#L12).

> ```
> def escape_item(val, charset, mapping=None):
>     if mapping is None:
>         mapping = encoders
>     encoder = mapping.get(type(val))
>
>     # Fallback to default when no encoder found
>     if not encoder:
>         try:
>             encoder = mapping[text_type]
>         except KeyError:
>             raise TypeError("no default type converter defined")
>
>     if encoder in (escape_dict, escape_sequence):
>         val = encoder(val, charset, mapping)
>     else:
>         val = encoder(val, mapping)
>     return val
> ```

This encoder, assuming the input is indeed a string, tries to call the `translate()` method on this string. But, since this method isn't defined for float64, you get this error.

You should try to convert your float64 to a regular float.

Or, you can create your own encoder, and add it in the `encoders` dict used as the default mapping of python types to encoder. If you're going to use a lot this lib with float64, it may be worth doing.

Comment: Thank you, I will update my question to ask followup

Comment: @Dylan From your sample, yes it's very likely this is the float64 causing the issue. So you should try `price = float(All_Tickers[str(length) + 'day_MA'][i])`.

Answer (score 12):

Add the command below to anywhere before making pymysql connection. It adds new encoder of numpy.float64.

```
pymysql.converters.encoders[np.float64] = pymysql.converters.escape_float
pymysql.converters.conversions = pymysql.converters.encoders.copy()
pymysql.converters.conversions.update(pymysql.converters.decoders)
```

Comment: As the answer says, please make sure to add these before making the pymysql connection. I got the same error as I was adding them at the point of query execution.

Answer (score 8):

You can solve this problem by just adding a float method for every np.float variable like below:

```
variable = float(variable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option, that could help it is:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
import numpy as np
import sqlalchemy

engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)

def add_own_encoders(conn, cursor, query, *args):
    cursor.connection.encoders[np.float64] = lambda value, encoders: float(value)

event.listen(engine, "before_cursor_execute", add_own_encoders)
```